# What would be the ideal artificially evolved human?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

**What would be the ideal form and structure for a human?**

We humans use tools to make up for our lack of everything, but honestly that's not very foolproof. Our best tool should be our body because our tools may not always be around to save us. My question concerns the physical aspect of our bodies and not the psychological (people are crazy creatures). **So how would you go about in creating the better human?**

What I can think of is a better skeletal system like bone plates instead of a rib cage. Back up organs like a second heart for survival. And an overall more animalistic appearance with keener senses, retractable claws and protection from the environment.

Comment: A tail isn't going to lower the stress on the back or neck. Claws will reduce out manual dexterity, humans artificially thin our skin with constant bathing so not an issue, a backup heart creates more problems than it solves, having a pouch has nothing to do with humans being born smaller, but this is a bad question anyway it is both onionon and list oriented. you would be better off asking if your list actually improves anything.

Comment: Alright now the question should be answerable without sounding too cheesy.

Comment: And actually ability to create tools for building more tools is a recognised distingishing feature of intelligance. You "superhuman" would not need one to survive - it would be just an aninmal. BUT, if he/she can transform their body to be the tool of their choice ...

Comment: Claws sound useful if you're not a tool-using species. Body plates sounds like they'd screw with your breathing. The problems that a second heart solves are few, etc etc. A question about specific ideas might be a better fit for the site, but as it stands this is still too broad, I think.

Comment: Best for what? Eating, hunting, controlling the nuclear reactor, steering a car, surviving an airplane crash... Each would require a vastly different human. Also some of your idea's are virtually impossible. A second heart? It's a sometimes used Sci-fi trope but where do you put it? It still needs to be close enough to the lungs, requires Aorta's to function, needs to get all the blood into it when the primary heart fails even though it's likely that if your primary heart is wounded that you lose all your blood and die anyway. Bone plates are heavy and rib cages need to move so you can breathe

Answer (score 3):

The idea of an ideal human body, is very much a matter of circumstance. Armor is only relevant if something is attacking you, otherwise it'll just add weight and slow you down. There are no advantages that can't be turned into a disadvantage under the right circumstance. Better eyesight would provide us with more information, but would require a larger part of our brain to process that information, leading to a higher energy consumption.

For us to specify an ideal, you would first have to set an environment for that ideal to be matched against. Otherwise there is no way to compare our solutions.

Comment: Exactly - organisms evolve in (and in reaction to) an environment. We need to know the environment for these humans and the circumstances they'll live in in order to determine the ideal features they would have

Answer (score 2):

**Nothing.**

Humans already survive from the deepest ocean to outer space. What can genetics give them that they can't give themselves?

The only changes needed is the removal of genetic diseases and imperfections. No more diabetes. No cancer. No birth defects. No more obesity.

I suppose regen would be nice but we're not far off growing organs and body parts now

Your suggested changes is a whole new species and as such is no longer human

Comment: Alright, case closed.

Answer (score 2):

Humans are designed to best suit a rather unique predatory niche of persistent distance hunters and we're darn good at it.  Humans are the fastest animal in an ultramarathon (100 mile run) mostly because everything else will need a much larger rest window than a typical human and our arms are capable of the most powerful throws in the animal kingdom (our nearest evolution relatives, specifically Chimps and Gorillas have a throw speed of 20 mph.  A professional pitcher on a baseball team can throw close to 100 mph pitches and children can typically best our ape cousins for throwing speed).  This is why we evolved high intelligence in the first place... throwing a stone or a stick or spear requires a great deal of mental math to know where the target will be when your projectile hits it.   We don't think about the math involved... because we've been hitting things with rocks for a long time... we instinctively can process some degree of certainty.   Few animals on earth kill at distance, and even fewer rely on accurate blows (most of the other need to get close enough that the shock wave will stun their prey... humans need to get accurate so their tools can fatally wound.).

Humans don't hold many records in the animal kingdom in raw terms... we can't out muscle a gorilla, out run a cheetah, and out swim an alligator... but we can out swim a gorilla or out climb a cheetah and out muscle or out run an alligator (If you know what your doing, especially out muscling gators).  Humans are remarkably flexible in what they can do... have an increadible endurance compared to any other animal (heance the afformentioned Ultramarathon record holding... a Cheetah is fast... for minutes at a time... humans are fast for hours at a time... every animal quits before we do with the closest next best being canines... which just so happen to be our best friends).

Humans are the animal kingdom's most lethal joke character... we're not the biggest or most offensive powerhouses around... but who needs that when you can kill from distance and continue to to close the gap on anything you want dead.   Remember we were causing the extinction of other animals long before we invented agriculture or the wheel.